# HighCharts - Thin white lines in stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to implement a stacked column chart in Highcharts. I have 360 datapoints and I would ideally not like any gap between the columns. I have already set borderwidth, pointpadding and grouppadding to 0, but still see the lines.

[Image of chart in Firefox and Chrome with thin white lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWLC0.jpg)

Edit: Updated with fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hgv5qtqj/7/. Thanks again!

Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant portion of code below:

```
       var plotOptions = {
      column: {
          pointPadding: 0,
          borderWidth: 0,
          groupPadding: 0,
         stacking: 'normal',
         dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
            style: {
               textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
            }
         }
      }
   };
```

Comment: Could you post live example of your chart? It is weird that pointPadding and groupPadding don't work in your case. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BZzWQ/271/

Comment: Thank you again. Have added the fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/hgv5qtqj/7/.

Comment: I think it is connected with this Highcharts issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4577

Comment: Thank you! Yes, adding the following code in the CSS did help. 

.highcharts-series {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges
}

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński - Please add your comment as an answer. It is absolutely right. I'm sure there are others who can benefit from it as an proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can include this in your `plotOptions`:

```
series: {
        borderWidth: 0
    }
```

More information on borderWidth is available in [HighCharts docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.borderWidth).

Comment: Thank you. Tried it, but it still looks the same.

Comment: Thank you. Have updated the post with the link to the fiddle. Thanks again for all your help.